# How do you run the beforerenderresponse event via managed bean

Tags: jsf, xpages, lotus-domino

I have managed been which i am using to handle the events on an XPage

The beforePageLoad event runs fine using EL to run the bean:

```
<xp:this.beforePageLoad><![CDATA[#{pageController.beforePageLoad}]]></xp:this.beforePageLoad>
```

However if i try the same with the beforeRenderResponse it does not run:

```
<xp:this.beforeRenderResponse><![CDATA[#{pageController.beforeRenderResponse}]]></xp:this.beforeRenderResponse>
```

If run the beforeRenderResponse event via SSJS it runs fine:

```
<xp:this.beforeRenderResponse><![CDATA[#{javascript:pageController.beforeRenderResponse();}]]></xp:this.beforeRenderResponse>
```

**Java**:

```
public class Controller{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7116804417284920609L;

    public void beforePageLoad() throws Exception {
        Logger.getInstance().logEvent("Controller.beforeRenderResponse", Logger.LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG);
    }
    public void afterPageLoad() throws Exception {
        Logger.getInstance().logEvent("Controller.beforeRenderResponse", Logger.LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG);
    }

    public boolean beforeRenderResponse() throws Exception {
        Logger.getInstance().logEvent("Controller.beforeRenderResponse", Logger.LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG);
    }
    public void afterRenderResponse() throws Exception {
        Logger.getInstance().logEvent("Controller.beforeRenderResponse", Logger.LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG);
    }

    public void afterRestoreView() throws Exception {
        Logger.getInstance().logEvent("Controller.beforeRenderResponse", Logger.LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG);
    }
}
```

Can somebody please advise how i can you run the beforeRenderResponse event using EL?

Answer (score 1):

If you open a Code Window in the beforeRenderResponse you will see that there is no dropDown list to select EL.

So its no use to force the use of EL if there is no possibility to add it to the before RenderResponse.
For more detailed Information on this you have to look deeper in the JSF Lifecycle.

A good book on this topic is [MasteringXpages](http://www.amazon.de/Mastering-XPages-Step-Step-Application/dp/0132486318) or take a look at  [XPageMasterclass](http://www.openntf.org/blogs/openntf.nsf/d6plinks/NHEF-95JAJV),   and [Peter Presnell](http://xpagesblog.com/XPagesHome.nsf/Entry.xsp?documentId=20B35C7A5E88ACD3852578CB006690E7).

Comment: There is no dropDown list to select EL for beforePageLoad but it works with EL.

Comment: Actually you can add EL using Simple Actions to `beforeRenderResponse` event. So your code would be something like `<xp:this.beforeRenderResponse><xp:executeScript script="#{pageController.beforeRenderResponse}"></xp:executeScript></xp:this.beforeRenderResponse>`.